# Filter by taxonomy parent using Json api

Tags: 8

In drupal 8.5 I have a taxonomy term list like this:

```
Term A (12 items)
  Term 1 (3 items)
  Term 2 (8 items)
  Term 3 (1 items)
Term B (3 items)
  Term 4 (1 items)
  Term 5 (2 items)
```

I want to use the json api to fetch all data within `term B`. So I expect a result set of 3 items.
But when I do:

```
https://www.some-api.com/jsonapi/node/test?
  _format=api_json&
  filter[taxFilter][condition][path]=field_regio&
  filter[taxFilter][condition][operator]=IN&
  filter[taxFilter][condition][value][]=2 (=> id of term B)
```

I get a response with `"data": [],` 
This is probably because the term id of these nodes are set to the children (term 4 and 5).

But isn't drupal supposed to return all nodes in the children of term B?

Otherwise how can I get all nodes in Term A or B?

Comment: You can just tag those nodes with the Parent term too right?

Comment: What is the point of the tree structure in taxonomy then? Some terms can have multiple parents, very hard for editors to know what all the parents are.

Comment: You don't have to force authors to do that, you can do it in a `hook_form_submit` programmatically too. But I think best way to go might be using Views, create a RESTful view that can work with hierarchical taxonomies, effectively replacing jsonapi for this call. `But isn't drupal supposed to return all nodes in the children of term B?` No, IIRC I don't think it works that way out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

The term-ID 2 belongs to "Term B", not to "Term 4" or "Term 5". To check if term belongs to Term B you may include the term parent and check if it has id 2:

```
https://www.some-api.com/jsonapi/node/test?
_format=api_json&
include=field_regio.parent
filter[taxFilter][condition][path]=field_regio.parent&
filter[taxFilter][condition][operator]=IN&
filter[taxFilter][condition][value][]=3 (=> id of term B)
```

This should work at least for the simple example provided it the question.

**See also D.A. question [How do you correctly filter on taxonomy terms to get all nodes matching term or parent term?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/291872) for more details and potential issue with permissions.**